# log4j not creating log files

Tags: java, log4j

Below is the log4j.properties file which i have used in a project to generate logs. But the logs are not getting generated at the mentioned location.

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file
#log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.org.apache.ibatis.MaxFileSize=15MB 
log4j.appender.org.apache.ibatis.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.File=E:\logs\file.log
log4j.appender.file.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

So I followed it up with writing a sample jsp as below and found that only `ConsoleAppender` class is returned by `out.println(app.getClass());` and this happens when I deploy the code in TOMCAT on windows server 2012. If the same code is deployed on windows server 2008 on TOMCAT, logs are generating properly as well as proper appender mentioned in properties file is returned. I have tried placing the log location inside and outside the Tomcat folder but still no luck. log4j version which we are using is 1.2.17.

```
<%@page import="org.apache.log4j.*"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%! static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("sample_jsp");
 %>
        <%
          Enumeration e = Logger.getRootLogger().getAllAppenders();
    while ( e.hasMoreElements() ){
      Appender app = (Appender)e.nextElement();
      out.println(app.getClass());
     if ( app instanceof ConsoleAppender ){
    //out.println("File: " + ((ConsoleAppender)app).getFile());
  }
  }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

What could be the reason for the abnormal behavior? Please help

Comment: Do you actually write anything to your logger? I would at least add a debug line for starters.

Comment: Yeah, the actual code has logger which is not writing to any log file.however if we change the logger to console appender it writes to stdout log

Comment: I can only suggest replacing `org.apache.ibatis` with `file` and using the rolling appender, since you have specified a `DatePattern`

Answer (score 0):

**log4j.properties**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,FILE,stdout
# Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File=automatio.out
log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p 
%c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=48
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=9

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p 
%c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

**In Baseclass.java**

```
    public void init() throws IOException 
    {
      String log4jConfPath="log4j.properties";
      PropertyConfigurator.configure(log4jConfPath);
    }

   public void log(String data) 
   {
      log.info(data);
      Reporter.log(data);   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check logs of app start up.

In my case project was deployed as WAR file to tomcat,
project had 2 SLF4J implementations, "log4j" and "logback".
On application deployment catalina.out had this message
"SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings....".
Removed logback by dependency exclusion in pom and after that file was created and populated by logs.

See this link
https://www.baeldung.com/slf4j-classpath-multiple-bindings